# Failing to install pandas, "maybe you forgot a comma"

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error

I dont really know why this is happening, Im just trying to install pandas to work with data and charts, but I cant install it on the IDLE neither on the terminal and it keeps giving me the same damn error code

I tried
`pip install pandas` it gave me: *SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?* in the IDLE

Then I proceeded to try installing pip cuz maybe I didnt have it?
`python -m ensurepip --default-pip` and it gave me the same error code.

Then I tried it in the terminal and same thing over and over again. I dont know why that is

Comment: "but I cant install it on the IDLE neither on the terminal and it keeps giving me the same damn error code" IDLE is a place to run actual Python code. What you are showing is not Python code; it is a command that you should use at the command line. You are supposed to understand these kinds of general things about *how to use the computer* before learning to program; but most people neglect to teach them properly nowadays.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ok... then what do I do?

Comment: Start by reading the duplicate that I linked. See the blue-shaded box at the top of the page? If not, refresh the page. Then click the link there, which will take you to a previous Stack Overflow question similar to yours. Read it, and the answers there, carefully, and follow that advice.